# How does the compiler know where to resume control after an await call

Tags: c#, async-await

REST calls are basically stateless calls. Then when we make an await call to a third party api, where does the compiler or control stores information about the place from where it needs to process once the await call is completed.

Comment: [Crash course in async and await](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20170720-00/?p=96655) by Raymond Chen may help. It also links to more in depth posts from Eric Lippert.

Comment: REST and state has nothing to do with it. The compiler already knows what statement or expression `await` is used on, and which statement comes after it. Just as it knows what expression or statement comes after a `==` or `;` or `+`

Comment: And it's not the compiler that does what you're asking, it's the runtime.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Actually, it *is* the compiler that constructs the [state machine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.iasyncstatemachine?view=netframework-4.8) that is used to implement async/await. You can see this if you use a decompiler to inspect the generated IL.

Comment: @MatthewWatson thanks. Learn something every day :-)

Answer (score 3):

> where does the compiler or control stores information about the place from where it needs to process once the await call is completed.

The [`async` keyword does two things](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html): it allows the use of the `await` keyword and it instructs the compiler to break up the `async` method into a state machine. The gory details are [here](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2011/05/08/eduasync-part-1-introduction/), but in summary:

The method is "split" at each use of `await`, with each "piece" of the method being a different part of the state machine. Then the current state of the state machine is saved (along with the values of local variables). When the awaited task completes, the continuation for that task executes the next step of the state machine.